# Able to connect to remote queue manager but not able to create topic connection

Tags: jms, ibm-mq

I am trying to publish a message to a remote JMS queue by a pretty standard mechanism:

```
TopicConnection tc = null;
TopicSession ts = null;
TopicPublisher tp = null;
Properties p = new Properties();
String providerUrl = "iiop://servername:9810";
String contextFactory = "com.ibm.websphere.naming.WsnInitialContextFactory".trim();
p.put(javax.naming.Context.PROVIDER_URL, providerUrl );
p.put(javax.naming.Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, contextFactory );
InitialContext ct = new InitialContext(p);

{                       
Topic topic = (Topic)ct.lookup( "jms/customer_event" );
TopicConnectionFactory tcf = (TopicConnectionFactory)ct.lookup( "jms/TopicFactory2" );
tc = tcf.createTopicConnection();
....
..
..
}
```

Now, the Topic and TopicConnectionFactory lookups are fine but when it comes to `tcf.createTopicConnection()`, it throws:

```
javax.jms.JMSException: MQJMS2005: failed to create MQQueueManager for 'servername:QMGR1'
Inner exception(s):
com.ibm.mq.MQException: MQJE001: Completion Code 2, Reason 2059
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
```

I opened up MQ explorer, and the topic is existing on the remote Queue manager. IS the TopicCoonectionFactory `TopicFactory2` also supposed to reside on the queue manager? Because it does not. 
What can be the cause of error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When connecting, the details of host, port and channel must be correct.  If the host or port are wrong, then the TCP socket is refused.  If the channel name is wrong, then the queue manager will refuse the connection and close the socket.  It is possible that you have all the details correct but that the listener on the queue manager is not running.

If the connection is getting as far as the queue manager then you will have an error in the `[WMQ Install dir]/qmgrs/[QMgr name]/errors/AMQERR01.LOG` file.  If the connection gets to WMQ but cannot resolve the queue manager's name or specifies the wrong QMgr then the error will be in `[WMQ Install dir]/errors/AMQERR01.LOG`.  If there is no entry in either of these then the connection isn't making it to WMQ and you need to check the listener or the network.

Comment: Thanks. All details are correct. For now i will accept your answer and investigate as per your suggestion.

Comment: There's a minor discrepancy in the post title which says "Able to connect to QMgr..." If you don't solve it with the advice given so far you might need to update the post to explain why you believe you are connected to the QMgr. The 2059 response code indicates the connection *wasn't* successful and that's what I based my response on.

Comment: Hello...I think that connection to queue manager was successful but topic connection failed. My reason is that in the error it actually shows the name of the queue manager as defined in websphere mq. If connection was not successful, how did it know what is the name of the queue manager?

Comment: Hmm...that error message looks like the QMgr name is defined as `servername:QMGR1` where I think it should be just `QMGR1`. That would cause the 2059 and an error logged to `/var/mqm/errors/AMQERR01.LOG`.Can you print out the managed object definitions and update the post? Specifically the connection factory but feel free to include the topic object as well.

Comment: Thanks. I solved the issue.The port 9810 is correct but the port defined in the TopicFactory2 was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

2059 connection refused is highly likely a network error or a typeo in the MQ server hostname and/or port. Double check your config in WebSphere and the network connection.

JavaDoc for ConnectException also states this http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/ConnectException.html

> Signals that an error occurred while attempting to connect a socket to a remote address and port. Typically, the connection was refused remotely (e.g., no process is listening on the remote address/port).

Comment: the possibility of n/w error and typo in hostname/port are less. Reason is that it is able to lookup the jndi names for Topic and TopicConnectionFactory without problem. It is also showing the name of the queue manager in the error message, but failing when trying to create a topic connection.